# Calculating derivatives inside of a loop for gradient descent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, sympy, calculus

Im quite new to NN and machine learning so i'm having trouble with something as simple as this. I'm writing a simple program that classifies if a flower is of one type or another.

I have my random weights assigned at first and want to adjust these inside of my training loop. I have my cost function running but cant seem to calculate derivatives of my cost wrt to each weight (w1 and w2) and the bias. I want to use the derivatives calculated to adjust my weights and bias. I'm using sympy at the moment but if I should be using another one please let me know.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp

# length, width, color
data = [[3, 1.5, 0], [2, 1, 1], [4, 1.5, 0], [3, 1, 1], [3.5, 0.5, 0], [2, 0.5, 1], [5.5, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
mystery_flower = [4.5, 1, '?']
learning_rate = 0.01

w1 = np.random.randn()
w2 = np.random.randn()
bias = np.random.randn()


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

for n in range(0, 10): #10 simply for testing
    random_index = np.random.randint(len(data))
    point = data[random_index]
    target = point[2]

    equation = w1*point[0] + w2*point[1] + bias
    prediction = sigmoid(equation)
    cost = (prediction - target) ** 2

    # Calculate derivaties for weights and bias wrt to cost
      dcost_dw1 = sp.diff(cost, wr1)

    # dcost_dw1 = dcost_dpred * dpred_deq * deq_dw1

    # Update weights and bias
```

I keep getting a value error every time I try to use `sp.diff()` inside my loop.
The error is `ValueError: Can't calculate derivative wrt 0.962802182433288.` Obviously the float changes for each loop

Comment: Where and how are you calling `sp.diff()`?  Please add this info to your question.

Comment: Note that you can't use `np.exp`in your sympy equations. You'll need `sp.exp`. Afterwards, use `lambdify` to convert the obtained sympy function to numpy.

Comment: @JohanC I've added it in

Comment: You probably need some kind of numerical derivative, not the symbolic sympy one.